# How to redirect when viewmodel return nothing because the value is not equal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Because one of the value is not exist or equal between column, the viewmodel return nothing so i try to redirect with make another view with model only. Or maybe there is a way to open the view even one of the value is null? All solution will be accept

Thanks for your help!

```
// GET: Form/Details/5
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Details(int? ID)
        {
            if (ID == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Toolreq appRequest = db.Toolreqs.Find(ID);
            List<TooldateViewModel> RequestView = new List<TooldateViewModel>();
            var result = (from p in db.Toolreqs
                          join x in db.Toolpurposes on p.PurposeId equals x.PurposeId
                          join z in db.Toollists on p.ToolId equals z.ToolId
                          where p.ID == ID && c.sch_attr == "FEP"
                          select new TooldateViewModel
                          {
                              ID = p.ID,
                              Status = p.Status,
                              Date_Request = p.Date_Request,
                              ...
                              sch_date = c.sch_date
                          }).ToList();
            if (result != null)
            {
                
                return View(result);
            }
            if (result == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("DetailsLess");
            }
            return View("");
        }
```

UPDATE!

"DetailsLess.cshtml" normal view without viewmodel that i want to redirect

```
@model LoginAndRegisterMVCMD5.Models.Toolreq
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DetailsLess";
}

<div>
    <h4>Toolreq</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Status)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date_Request)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Date_Request)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.ID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Comment: Could you share your action where you would like to redirect once no data found? Or defination of your viewModel will be fine as well.

Comment: We can return empty viewModel creating its new instance that will also fine. Can you share `DetailsLess` view?

Comment: No problem, wait a while.

Comment: Updated sir, and the problem is, it is not redirect at all even when the viewmodel is null, sorry the view is still so plain

Comment: Try the solution and let me know if you have any further concern.

Comment: Yes sir! will implement it asap

Comment: Sure, It will resolve you issue completely.

Comment: Let, me correct you, I am as simple as you, a learner, nothing more. Just debug more, I promise it will make you stronger. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Because one of the value is not exist or equal between column, the
> viewmodel return nothing so i try to redirect with make another view
> with model only. Or maybe there is a way to open the view even one of
> the value is null?

Well, as per your shared code snippet it seems your appreach is correct. However, few things need to check and implemenet to make it work. Here are the details:

Firstly, Make sure, `appRequest` or  `result` doesn't encounter any exception in that scenario your `if (result == null)` will not executed.

Secondly, Your `@model LoginAndRegisterMVCMD5.Models.Toolreq` on `DetailsLess` view must allow null result other than in between it will cought error and would not redirect.

**Solution:**

Your `Toolreq` model should allow null value just as below:

```
public class Toolreq
    {
        public string? Status { get; set; }
        public string? Date_Request { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public int? Qty { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** Please add rest of the property based on your needs.

**Controller:**

Controller where you would redirect

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DetailsLess()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "No Data Found By This ID";
            return View();
        }
```

Your Main Controller

```
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Details(int? ID)
        {
            //Set Try... Catch Block here if possibility of exception
            if (ID == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Toolreq appRequest = db.Toolreqs.Find(ID);
            List<TooldateViewModel> RequestView = new List<TooldateViewModel>();
            var result = (from p in db.Toolreqs)... ToList();//
          
            if (result == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("DetailsLess");
            }
            return View(result);
        }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** Make sure in your view of `DetailsLess` accept null model value `@model LoginAndRegisterMVCMD5.Models.Toolreq`. To do that you can allow null to all property Like this `public string? Status`.

Answer (score 0):

Last Result, big thanks to @Md Farid Uddin Kiron

Main Controller:

```
// GET: Form/Details/5
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Details(int? ID)
{
    if (ID == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    List <TooldateViewModel> RequestView = new List<TooldateViewModel>();
    RequestView = (from p in db.Toolreqs
                  join x in db.Toolpurposes on p.PurposeId equals x.PurposeId
                  join z in db.Toollists on p.ToolId equals z.ToolId
                  where p.ID == ID && c.sch_attr == "FEP"
                  select new TooldateViewModel
                  {
                      ID = p.ID,
                      Status = p.Status,
                      Date_Request = p.Date_Request,
                      ...
                      sch_date = c.sch_date
                  }).ToList();
    if (RequestView?.Any() != true)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("DetailsLess", "Form", new { ID = ID });
    }
    return View(RequestView);
}
```

The controller we aim:

```
// GET: Form/Details/5
public ActionResult DetailsLess(int? ID)
{
    if (ID == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Toolreq toolreq = db.Toolreqs.Find(ID);
    if (toolreq == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(toolreq);
}
```